# Openshift Origin 1.5.1 Pod anti-affinity on DeploymentConfig not working

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

I have a strange issue where I am trying to apply a PodAntiAffinity to make sure that no 2 pods of the specific deploymentConfig ever end up on the same node:

I attempt to edit the dc with:

```
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    app: server-config
    deploymentconfig: server-config
  strategy:
    activeDeadlineSeconds: 21600
    resources: {}
    rollingParams:
      intervalSeconds: 1
      maxSurge: 25%
      maxUnavailable: 25%
      timeoutSeconds: 600
      updatePeriodSeconds: 1
    type: Rolling
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: server-config
        deploymentconfig: server-config
    spec:
      affinity:
        podAntiAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
          - labelSelector:
              matchExpressions:
              - key: app
                operator: In
                values:
                - server-config
            topologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"
```

but on saving that, I get a :

```
"/tmp/oc-edit-34z56.yaml" 106L, 3001C written
deploymentconfig "server-config" skipped
```

and the changes dont stick. My openshift/Kubernetes versions are:

```
[root@master1 ~]# oc version
oc v1.5.1
kubernetes v1.5.2+43a9be4
features: Basic-Auth GSSAPI Kerberos SPNEGO
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Open to correction, but I think that feature was not added to OpenShift until 3.6

Comment: found the first mention of podantiaffinity in container platform 3.3:
https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.3/admin_guide/manage_nodes.html#pod-anti-affinity

and in the 3.5 release notes it states that OCP 3.5 is based on origin 1.5:
https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.5/release_notes/ocp_3_5_release_notes.html

So from what I can see its compatible

Comment: I did say I was open to correction :) Have you made this change? `The last required step is to enable the MatchInterPodAffinity scheduler predicate in /etc/origin/master/scheduler.json.`

Comment: Thanks Phillip, your comment actually pointed me in the right direction anyway. Checking out the scheduling predicates further, it seems MatchInterPodAffinity is a default predicate in OCP 3.5/Origin 1.5:  
https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.5/admin_guide/scheduler.html
Thanks again !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work, the syntax is wildly different and the "scheduler.alpha.kubernetes.io/affinity" annotation needs to be added to work:

```
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    app: server-config
    deploymentconfig: server-config
  strategy:
    activeDeadlineSeconds: 21600
    resources: {}
    rollingParams:
      intervalSeconds: 1
      maxSurge: 25%
      maxUnavailable: 25%
      timeoutSeconds: 600
      updatePeriodSeconds: 1
    type: Rolling
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        scheduler.alpha.kubernetes.io/affinity: |
          {
            "podAntiAffinity": {
              "requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution": [{
                "labelSelector": {
                  "matchExpressions": [{
                    "key": "app",
                    "operator": "In",
                    "values":["server-config"]
                  }]
                },
                "topologyKey": "kubernetes.io/hostname"
              }]
            }
          }
```

Working as intended and spreading out properly between nodes:

```
[root@master1 ~]# oc get pods -o wide |grep server-config
server-config-22-4ktvf                      1/1       Running   0          3h        10.1.1.73    10.0.4.101
server-config-22-fz31j                      1/1       Running   0          3h        10.1.0.3     10.0.4.100
server-config-22-mrw09                      1/1       Running   0          3h        10.1.2.64    10.0.4.102
```